# How to get attribute of an Object in Hibernate @Filter condition?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following mapped super class:

```
    @FilterDef(
        name = "byCompanyUuid",
        parameters = @ParamDef(
                name = "companyUuid",
                type = "string"
        )
)
@Filter(
        name = "byCompanyUuid",
        condition = "COMPANY.UUID = :companyUuid"
)
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract  class CompanyAuditableEntity extends AbstractAuditableEntity {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "COMPANY")
    protected CompanyEntity company;


    public CompanyEntity getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(CompanyEntity company) {
        this.company = company;
    }
}
```

I want to get "UUID" parameter of companyEntity object and make sure that it's equal to :companyUuid param. I'm struggling for a whole day how to achieve this. Can someone help me out if this is even possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As it described in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-filter):

> The `@Filter` condition uses a SQL condition and not a JPQL filtering predicate.

So, you should use actual table/column names in the `@Filter` condition.

Also according to [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-filter-sql-fragment-alias):

> When using the `@Filter` annotation and working with entities that are mapped onto multiple database tables, you will need to use the `@SqlFragmentAlias` annotation if the `@Filter` defines a condition that uses predicates across multiple tables.

Comment: I have tried setting the alias as following: @Filter(
        name = "byCompanyUuid",
        condition = "{c}.UUID = :companyUuid",
        aliases ={@SqlFragmentAlias( alias = "c", entity= CompanyEntity.class)}
)                                                             but then i get that this enttiy doesnt exist (it is properly annotated with @Entity and  exists in db). I also tried with table name but same result, just now i got that table doesnt exist.

Comment: To be honest I am not sure that you can use `@Filter` with `@MappedSuperclass` at all. As it described [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#annotations-hibernate-filter): `The @Filter annotation is used to add filters to an entity or the target entity of a collection.` But annotation `@MappedSuperclass` does not make annotated class an entity.

Comment: It can be used with it. I have another filter which does exactly the same thing, just the attribute is plain String and it works properly. This one doesn't and i can't figure out how to filter property of this object.